# How to run a c program in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

Hello i am new to ubuntu. I want to run a c program in ubuntu.On the terminal i typed "make ex1.c" (my file name is ex1) and the after pressing enter button , terminal is telling me that
"no rule to make target 'ex1.c'. stop " .

How can i proceed?

Comment: Make needs a makefile, check the manual.https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html

Comment: `make` doesn't need a makefile. `make ex1` will run perfectly fine.

Comment: I learn something everyday! Dang. I will not go off topic, but I have to wonder why they permit that...

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
$ gcc -Wall ex1.c -o ex1
$ ./ex1
```

`-Wall` makes all the warnings explicit. It is considered to be a good practice to always enable `-Wall` option. `-o ex1` specifies the output executable to be `ex1`.

`GCC` is the default C compiler on `Ubuntu`. An elegant introduction to `gcc` can be read in [here](http://www.tunl.duke.edu/documents/public/root/material/5/An_Introduction_to_GCC-Brian_Gough.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

`make` needs no rules to make a simple C file, all it needs is the basename, without the `.c` extension:

```
make ex1
./ex1
```

I advise you to start using the `gcc` command though. You will have more control on how stuff is compiled and along the way, you'll learn how building an application works. `make` will start making sense if you have a larger project with many (inter dependent) files.

More (a lot!) information here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/, or by typing `man gcc` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use GCC or you are getting error because you are attaching ".c".So don't put extension in make command.Try without putting extension like following:

```
make ex1
./ex1
```